# YouTube automation with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, youtube

I want to automate youtube with selenium and python completely. the following tasks are to be accomplished. the problem is with points number 4 and 6. how to handle them?

1. open youtube
2. search any video
3. play any video
4. pause the  video
5. like dislike the video.
6. play the next video

   ```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

    Search_Box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')   #search bar
    speak("opend sir what shoud i search ?")
    query=takecommand().lower()
    # query=input('data ?') 
    Search_Box.send_keys(query)
    Search_Button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]') #clicked search button
    Search_Button.click()
    speak("searched now which one ?")


    query=takecommand().lower()
    # query=input('data ?')
    if "first" in query:
        video_number = 1
        select_video1=driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@id='video-title'])[{video_number}]").click()
        # select_video1.click()
    elif 'second' in query:
        video_number = 2
        select_video2=driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@id='video-title'])[{video_number}]").click()
        time.sleep(5)
        speak('pausing video')
        select_video2=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('movie_player > div.ytp-chrome-bottom > div.ytp-chrome-controls > div.ytp-left-controls > button').click()  #this was for pause,but didnt worked here
   ```

Comment: @Codelt   'select_video2=driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"(//a[@id='video-title'])[{video_number}]").click() '                                                                                            for this how can i send  k (stop) button ? simple send keys is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these...

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# won't work unless you are logged in
like_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//yt-icon[@class='style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer'])[4]")))
like_btn.click()

# won't work unless you are logged in
dislike_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//yt-icon[@class='style-scope ytd-toggle-button-renderer'])[5]")))
dislike_btn.click()

pause_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Pause (k)']")))
pause_btn.click()

# comment out to test pause btn, otherwise it happens so fast you don't notice
play_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Play (k)']")))
play_btn.click()

mute_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Mute (m)']")))
mute_btn.click()

# comment out to test mute_btn, otherwise it happens so fast you don't notice it
unmute_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Unmute (m)']")))
unmute_btn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To play or pause video you can click the play / pause button located by the following `css_selector`: `button.ytp-play-button`
To go to the next video click the following element `a.ytp-next-button`. again, it's `css-selector`

Comment: tried the following but didn't work       
 pause=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('button.ytp-play-button').click() '

Comment: This button appears not immediately, only after the video is loaded and started playing. So you need to put a wait before it

Comment: put a timer of 5 seconds after playing the video, but didn't work, and don't give error